# CKAN Data Explorer - filter and download

Tags: csv, ckan

Can anyone suggest a datasource code edit or extension to allow users to create a subset of a resource (CSV) by using the filter in the Data Explorer?

So once a filter is applied users are able to download the filtered data (i.e. the subset) directly from the Data Explorer screen?

Thanks

Mikey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension [Data explorer](https://github.com/keitaroinc/ckanext-dataexplorer)  adds the functionality that you need. It is similar to recline view plus has options for downloading filtered data. The documentation is bad but I think it is easy to setup(same as all other ckan extensions).

Comment: Thanks, that works. Although the size of the dataset added, 17m rows (3gb), is causing a problem, error in the logs is that the api is taking too long to search the data. It's on a AWS t2.medium instance currently. Any suggestions, aside from upping the spec.